# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right)=0$ using $\varepsilon$-$N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I don't know how to figure it out. The following image shows my question: 
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3UXS.png)

> Prove $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right)=0$$ using $\varepsilon$-$N$ argument.

My try:
$$\left\lvert \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right) \right\rvert=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\times n$$

I do not know how to continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\left|\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right)\right|\le \frac32$ for $n\ge 1$ (you can use induction to show this).  Therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\left(\frac23\right)^n\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right)\right|&\le \left(\frac23\right)^{n-1}<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>\max\left(1,1+\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(2/3)}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Chopin You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: Since you're new to the site, I wanted to let you know that when you have enough reputation points, you can up vote answers too.  ;-)) -Mark